# zend2 + doctrine 2 Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException' $jobId does not exist

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I am new to zend 2 and Doctrine 2. I tried to create an entity class but got the following message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException' with message
>   '[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\jobId" in
>   property Workers\Entity\Jobsought::$jobId does not exist, or could not
>   be auto-loaded

Below is the entity class

```
namespace Workers\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface; 

/**
 * 
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="worker_main_jobsort")
 * @property int $jobId
 */
class Jobsought implements InputFilterAwareInterface 
{
    protected $inputFilter;

    /**
     * @ORM\jobId
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $jobId;


    /**
     * Magic getter to expose protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($property) 
    {
        return $this->$property;
    }

    /**
     * Magic setter to save protected properties.
     *
     * @param string $property
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function __set($property, $value) 
    {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the ORM cannot map it? The table exist in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Also just started out using the two of these combined - but think I know what your issue is.

First off, you can't try specifying any "strange" (according to doctrine strange) annotations without using the @ignore directive.

Secondly, I think you're trying to say with `@property int $jobId` that `"$jobId"` is your PK? Well you're already doing so when you say `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")`, telling doctrine to map jobid to be your PK. Also, I read somewhere that adding `name="job_id"` to your `@Column` annotation is good practice, but don't quote me on that. Guess it doesn't really matter.

Hope this helps!

Edit -

My bad, also missed that you need to remove `@ORM\jobId` as it's not a valid doctrine annotation (jobId that is). Just specify it as `@ORM\Id` and you should be fine.